# Buscar con Cypress el boton Delete de una fila en una tabla

Tags: reactjs, test

Estoy empezando a trastear con Cypress para probar un sencillo front que tengo en React.

Pues bien, el front muestra una lista de contactos (nombre, apellido, telefono y mail).

Quiero hacer una prueba con Cypress que me busque uno de estos contactos por, por ejemplo, el nombre, se vaya a la ultima columna de esta tabla (que contiene un grupo de botones) y busque el botón delete, y lo borre.
Soy capaz de buscar el nobre en la tabla:

`cy.get("table").contains("td", "first name");`

Pero no de buscar el boton delete, estoy itentnado hacer algo tal que asi, pero no hay manera:

`cy.get('.btn btn-danger contactlist-btn-space [type="button"]').click();`

¿Alguien puede decirme que se me está escapando?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

hice esto:

```
 cy.get("table")
      .contains("td", "first name")
      .siblings()
      .get("div")
      .contains("button", "Delete")
      .click();
```

y me funcionó